# Sign private key pair with sha-256 in python

Tags: python, encryption-asymmetric

I want to know how can I sign my private key with sha-256. I already tried it, but it didn't work.. how can I do it properly? by the way I'm using a asymmetric encryption to encrypt all files that are transferred via network.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
    from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
    from OpenSSL import SSL
    import socket
    import hashlib
    import os

    #load public key
    def publicKey():
        with open('public_key.key', 'r') as public_file:
            public_key = RSA.importKey(public_file.read())

    #load private key
    def privateKey():
        with open('private_key.key', 'r') as private_file:
            private_key = RSA.importKey(private_file.read())

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        txt = input("what do you want to do?")
```

Comment: At first: asymetric encryption requires a large ammount of computing power, for bulk transfers if is better to use symetric encryption and RSA only for exchanging keys. Also, your code does not show any encryption. So what have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm not using embedded public/private key. I'm loading them from a extern file

Comment: wait. am I doing wrong so far? do I have to change my code to symetric encryption and after use rsa with that string?

Comment: Signing a message means you generate something which proves that whoever sent the message has access to your private key.  If you send your private key to other people, your signature is meaningless.  So I'm not sure what it means to sign your private key.

Answer (score 2):

```
signature = hmac.new(key=private_key, message, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
```

Comment: Please use snippets only for stuff that actually works with them.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.